# Сравнить звук в Unity

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Подскажите как можно сравнить 2 звуковые дорожки по названию 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть азбука со звуками букв хочу провесит проверку их знаний так скажем,
чтобы в начале воспроизводился звук рандомной буквы(массив звуков как на скриншоте  и код:)

```html
 void Awake()
   {
    _as = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

   }

   void Start()
   {

        _as.clip=audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)];
        _as.PlayOneShot(_as.clip);
```

а после нажимать на определенный спрайт или кнопку за который закреплен звук

```html
void OnMouseDown()
       {
          _as.Play();
```

и проигрывать любую кнопку которую он воспроизвел и если правильно то +1 очко если нет -1 очко так скажем, и заного воспроизводим звук и по накатанной

Comment: audio1 и audio2 - это что? Файлы? Названия переменных?

Comment: Вот правил что именно

Comment: Я все равно не понимаю, что вы хотите. Соблюдайте, пожалуйста, правила пунктуации и исправьте имена в тексте, скриншот не несет никакого толка в пояснении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AudioClip - класс, который представляет собой дорожки в Unity наследуется от Object, а он, в свою очередь имеет поле .name - т.е. имя объекта.

Если хотите - можете сравнить объекты по имени, если не хотите, то просто через ==. Обычный == между объектами сравнит ссылки на загруженные в память объекты и если обе переменные ведут на один и тот же объект, то вам выдаст true.

```
    bool ClipRefEquals(AudioClip clip0, AudioClip clip1)
    {
        return clip0 == clip1;
    }

    bool ClipNameEquals(AudioClip clip0, AudioClip clip1)
    {
        return clip0.name == clip1.name;
    }
```

После уточнения вопроса - могу уточнить и ответ.
Каждый из ваших AudioClip - это отдельный object, т.е. он хранится в оперативной памяти в единственном экземляре. Т.е. если у вас есть две переменные, которые ссылаются на AudioClip и вы хотите узнать не ссылаются ли они на один и тот же, то вы можете просто сравнить их через ==. Базовая реализация сравнит ссылки, а т.к. сам клип лежит в памяти в одном экземпляре, то и ссылки на него совпадут.

Comment: Могу я использовать if(clip0.name == clip1.name) и тогда выполняется определенное действие а нет то другое? и могу ли я использовать массив 
 из множества клипов как в скриншоте и сравнить с одним по нажатию?

Comment: @ratmirpupkin, вы опишите какую проблему хотите решить, а я, возможно, подскажу как) так-то да - можете использовать

Comment: написал более подробно в главном вопросе

Comment: @ratmirpupkin уточнил ответ